# Reverse A Binary Tree (Left to Right)

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, reverse

I was looking at interview questions and I recently came upon one that asked you how to reverse a general binary tree, like flip it from right to left.

So for example if we had the binary tree

```
     6
   /   \
  3     4
 / \   / \
7   3 8   1
```

Reversing it would create

```
     6
   /   \
  4     3
 / \   / \
1   8 3   7
```

You can see that the new tree is the mirror image of the original tree.

I haven't been able to think of a good implementation on how to solve this problem. Can anyone offer any good ideas?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can use recursion. We swap the left and right child of a node, in-place, and then do the same for its children:

```
static void reverseTree(final TreeNode root) {
    final TreeNode temp = root.right;
    root.right = root.left;
    root.left = temp;
    
    if (root.left != null) {
        reverseTree(root.left);
    }
    
    if (root.right != null) {
        reverseTree(root.right);
    }
}
```

To handle the case where the parameter `root` may be null:

```
static void reverseTree(final TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return;
    }
    
    final TreeNode temp = root.right;
    root.right = root.left;
    root.left = temp;
    
    reverseTree(root.left);
    
    reverseTree(root.right);
}
```

Answer (score 28):

Reverse a binary tree in O(1) in C/C++.

```c
struct NormalNode {
  int value;
  struct NormalNode *left;
  struct NormalNode *right;
};

struct ReversedNode {
  int value;
  struct ReversedNode *right;
  struct ReversedNode *left;
};

struct ReversedNode *reverseTree(struct NormalNode *root) {
  return (struct ReversedNode *)root;
}
```

Comment: How does that cast work in [tag:java]?  I think you're answering a different question.

Comment: he awnser is right, it's not suited to java through, but work well with c/c++

Comment: This answer made me laugh (in a good way). Gotta love dark C++ magic :D

Comment: Isn't this a violation of strict aliasing rules in C++ and therefore undefined behaviour?

Comment: It does not revert the binary tree - note how NormalNode and ReversedNode is of different type, so when you e.g. might invert a tree, or might not, you need an extra bit to represent which case it is. And what if I want to invert a subtree of a binary tree? (that is also by definition a binary tree). So now you need an extra bit on every level, and accessing each node require a jump. The datastructure is then sacrificing huge read perf for inversion perf.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple interesting parts to this question. First, since your language is Java, you're most likely to have a generic Node *class*, something like this:

```
class Node<T> {
    private final T data;
    private final Node left;
    private final Node right;
    public Node<T>(final T data, final Node left, final Node right) {
        this.data  = data;
        this.left  = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
    ....
}
```

Secondly, reversing, sometimes called inverting, can be done either by mutating the left and right fields of the node, or by creating a *new* node just like the original but with its left and right children "reversed." The former approach is shown in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9460287/831878), while the second approach is shown here:

```
class Node<T> {
    // See fields and constructor above...

    public Node<T> reverse() {
        Node<T> newLeftSubtree = right == null ? null : right.reverse();
        Node<T> newRightSubtree = left == null ? null : left.reverse();
        return Node<T>(data, newLeftSubtree, newRightSubtree); 
    }
}
```

The idea of not mutating a data structure is one of the ideas behind [persistent data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure), which are pretty interesting.

Comment: shouldn't the right be the left reverse and the left the the right reverse?

Comment: The swapping is done when constructing a new Node: i.e. that's why the right comes before the left. It is not clear because the constructor has not been given.

Comment: Good call, @amnn and thanks for the initial edit. Java's lack of named arguments is a bit of a bummer, being able to say `new Node(data=data, left=right?.reverse(), right=left?.reverse())` would be awesome but Java is not there yet. We could also do `new Node().withData(data).withLeft(right.reverse.......).withRight(left.reverse......)` etc. I ended up just making the `reverse` method a little more readable by using named local variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively swap the left and right nodes as below;

```
// helper method
private static void reverseTree(TreeNode<Integer> root) {
    reverseTreeNode(root);
}

private static void reverseTreeNode(TreeNode<Integer> node) {
    TreeNode<Integer> temp = node.left;
    node.left   = node.right;
    node.right  = temp;

    if(node.left != null)
        reverseTreeNode(node.left);

    if(node.right != null)
        reverseTreeNode(node.right);
}
```

## Demonstration Code for Java

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class InvertBinaryTreeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // root node
        TreeNode<Integer> root  = new TreeNode<>(6);

        // children of root
        root.left               = new TreeNode<Integer>(3);
        root.right              = new TreeNode<Integer>(4);

        // grand left children of root
        root.left.left          = new TreeNode<Integer>(7);
        root.left.right         = new TreeNode<Integer>(3);

        // grand right childrend of root
        root.right.left         = new TreeNode<Integer>(8);
        root.right.right        = new TreeNode<Integer>(1);

        System.out.println("Before invert");
        traverseTree(root);

        reverseTree(root);

        System.out.println("\nAfter invert");
        traverseTree(root);
    }

    // helper method
    private static void reverseTree(TreeNode<Integer> root) {
        reverseTreeNode(root);
    }

    private static void reverseTreeNode(TreeNode<Integer> node) {
        TreeNode<Integer> temp = node.left;
        node.left   = node.right;
        node.right  = temp;

        if(node.left != null)
            reverseTreeNode(node.left);

        if(node.right != null)
            reverseTreeNode(node.right);
    }

    // helper method for traverse
    private static void traverseTree(TreeNode<Integer> root) {
        Queue<Integer> leftChildren     = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<Integer> rightChildren    = new LinkedList<>();

        traverseTreeNode(root, leftChildren, rightChildren);

        System.out.println("Tree;\n*****");

        System.out.printf("%3d\n", root.value);

        int count = 0;
        int div = 0;
        while(!(leftChildren.isEmpty() && rightChildren.isEmpty())) {
            System.out.printf("%3d\t%3d\t", leftChildren.poll(), rightChildren.poll());
            count += 2;
            div++;
            if( (double)count == (Math.pow(2, div))) {
                System.out.println();
                count = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void traverseTreeNode(TreeNode<Integer> node, Queue<Integer> leftChildren, Queue<Integer> rightChildren) {
        if(node.left != null)
            leftChildren.offer(node.left.value);

        if(node.right != null)
            rightChildren.offer(node.right.value);

        if(node.left != null) {
            traverseTreeNode(node.left, leftChildren, rightChildren);
        }

        if(node.right != null) {
            traverseTreeNode(node.right, leftChildren, rightChildren);
        }
    }

    private static class TreeNode<E extends Comparable<E>> {

        protected E value;
        protected TreeNode<E> left;
        protected TreeNode<E> right;

        public TreeNode(E value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
        }

    }

}
```

## Output

```
Before invert
Tree;
*****
  6
  3   4 
  7   3   8   1 

After invert
Tree;
*****
  6
  4   3 
  1   8   3   7
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursion function can be very simple as shown below:

```
public Node flipTree(Node node) {
    if(node == null) return null;

    Node left = flipTree(node.left);
    Node right = flipTree(node.right);

    node.left = right;
    node.right = left;

    return node;
}
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering code-only. At least demonstrate why it solves the problem, and explain the code, either in text or comments, so that future readers will be able to understand it.

Comment: To be fair the top voted answer also is code-only. That being said, it's worth looking at existing answers before adding your own. Your answer is exactly the same as the top voted answer so in general it's better to just upvote that answer rather than add your own duplicate answer.

Answer (score -2):

I've seen most of the answers aren't focussing on null pointer issues.

```
public static Node invertBinaryTree(Node node) {

    if(node != null) {
        Node temp = node.getLeftChild();

        node.setLeftChild(node.getRightChild());
        node.setRigthChild(temp);

        if(node.left!=null) { 
            invertBinaryTree(node.getLeftChild());
        }
        if(node.right !=null) {
            invertBinaryTree(node.getRightChild());
        }
    }

    return node;
}
```

In the code above we are making recursive calls only if the left/right child of the root node isn't null. Its one of the fastest approach!